# Comparing equality of Collections in JPA

Tags: jpa, jpql

First of all i'll demonstrate backgorund of this problem...

I tried to make fast and redudant-free implementation of a repository. Problematic object looks like this:

```
class SomeObject {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private List<SomeData>;
    private List<SomeOtherData>;

    ....
}
```

SomeData and SomeOtherData are Entities, and they're normally mapped by JPA. Later i've made SomeObject instances immutable, which enables some further optimalization. SomeObject becomed interchangeable, and i don't want to make duplicates in db. In order to find possible duplicate i need to compare those lists.

The main question arises: How to check equality of SomeData collection in SomeObject (order is meaningless) with some arbitrary collection of SomeData (supilled as parameter) ?

I've tried workaround by combining JPA SIZEOF and dozens of MEMBER BY to ensure equality of both collections. It worked but performance was absolutely horrible.

Answer (score 0):

Using HashSet's and implementing hashcode/equals in your two classes might solve your problem, you could also use a @PrePersist method to ensure that you applying the filter consistently. If you need more complicated filtering maybe look into org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils. It is assumed that you are also using a unique constraint in your database if duplicates are not acceptable.

Comment: Let me clarify this, i want to find duplicate using jpql. HashSet can work - if you fetch all entities from database and and them to Set. Database constraints are not database agnostic, so you loose the most powerfull feature of ORM.

Comment: Also, constraints on the table will fail all attepmts to add duplicate, that's not what we want. You still need to find this duplicate to share it's id...